# Root N1 and keep the official ROM

Tags: rooting, nexus-one

Is it possible root my N1 with 2.3.3 without flashing custom ROM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  According to [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=972831), you can unlock the bootloader with fastboot and then flash only a custom recovery.  The custom recovery will allow you to put `su` on your device.

You could also flash a stock 2.3.3 ROM that has been altered slightly (i.e., pre-rooted).  For example, [this one over at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=968499).