# How can I root my Nexus One?

Tags: rooting, nexus-one

I want to give root permission to my Android Nexus One phone. I tried several links to give root access, but could not find any single working solution. Most links suggest to download a copy of a superboot image matching my kernel version. I could not find one that matches the kernel version with steps to give root permission. Any help?

Comment: have you looked here? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device

Comment: @Bryan Just as a heads up, we're moving away from that centralized post (see [here](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/790/1465)) so this question is fine to stay.  Thanks for linking it though, I think the method that post links to might still work.

Comment: So maybe [Root N1 and keep the official ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6592/16575) is the better address?